# Symbol "ɵ" (Greek Theta) isn't escaped during angular 8 build

Tags: angular, encoding, build, escaping, unexpected-token

I'm building an angular 8 application for production inside an Azure DevOps pipeline.

Although the build completes without any error, I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??'` in the browser at execution time.

The main.js chunk file generated by the build, contains the symbol "ɵ" (Greek Theta), for example: `t.ɵcompilerFacade` that becomes `t.??compilerFacade` when it's served to the browser.

If I use angular 7, the symbol "ɵ" is escaped to "\u0275" during the build, for example: `t.\u0275compilerFacade`, which works fine in the browser.

It seems to be an encoding issue.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

---

**ANGULAR 8 ENVIRONMENT**

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.25",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    ...
}
```

File generated after the build

[image]

---

File served

[image: Chunk main.js file]

---

Error shown in the browser console

[image: Browser console]

---

**ANGULAR 7 ENVIRONMENT**

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    ...
}
```

File generated after the build

[image]

---

File served

[image]

---

No error shown in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which I managed to fix by ensuring the build optimizer was enabled. Set `"buildOptimizer": true` in your `angular.json` file. This requires AOT compilation to be enabled.

In Angular9, there's an `"optimization"` option in the same config block that also seems to enable unicode escaping but does not require AOT.

Comment: Hi @markdBC. In my angular.json I have `"optimization": true, "aot": true, "buildOptimizer": true`. I'm also using the `ng build` command with the `--prod` meta-flag which compiles with AOT by default. The problem seems to be related to the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` package. I found a open issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16253).

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue appear seemingly out of nowhere. Although we never did pin down exactly what caused it to start happening, we determined that it could be fixed by changing the `Content-Type` response header from `application/javascript` to `application/javascript;charset=UTF-8`. How you do that will depend on your webserver; in our case, using Tomcat 9, that meant adding the following to the `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>js</extension>
  <mime-type>application/javascript;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```